# Hide a folder in android studio project view

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

How can I hide a package folder in Android studio project view?. I am unable to find any answer about hiding any thing from any project view inside Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the settings of project view(right side of the toolbar) click "hide Empty Middle Packages"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for this menu

[image]

Comment: No, I am using Android project view and I want to hide some packages inside Android project view. Is it possible?